# Assigning a unique_ptr to a raw pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm trying to link a node to another node using unique pointers. I managed to do it with the code below, but it feels like bad code because its so long winded . How can I improve this?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;    
    unique_ptr<Node<T>> nextNode;

    Node(T dataIn) : data(dataIn), nextNode(nullptr) {                   
    }

    void setNextNode(Node<T> * nodeIn) {          
      unique_ptr<Node<T>> newNextNode(nodeIn);
      nextNode = std::move(newNextNode);                 
    }   

    void printData() {
      cout << data << endl;
    }
};

int main() {      
  unique_ptr<Node<int>> root(new Node<int>(26));    
  Node<int> * nodeTwo = new Node<int>(88);      
  root->setNextNode(nodeTwo);   
}
```

Comment: Mixing unique_ptr with raw pointer isn't smart. You can std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> newNextNode = std:: make_unique<Node<T>>(*nodeIn);

Comment: Herb Sutter wrote up a nice explanation for when to use raw pointers, references, unique_ptr, unique_ptr references, shared_ptr, and shared_ptr references.  May seem a bit overwhelming at first, because of the number of options, but each has a distinct use case (or "never use" use case).  [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use rvalue reference and swap that moves:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node {


public:
    T data;
    unique_ptr<Node<T>> nextNode;

    Node(T dataIn) : data(dataIn), nextNode(nullptr) {

    }

    void setNextNode(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> &&nodeIn) {
            std::swap(nextNode, nodeIn);
    }

    void printData() {
      cout << data << endl;
    }



};




int main() {
  unique_ptr<Node<int>> root(new Node<int>(26));
  root->setNextNode(std::make_unique<Node<int>>(88));
  root->nextNode->printData();

}
```

Short comment is that you should not convey unique_ptrs from other palces as the whole point of it to show ownership, so that's being said change setNextNode:

```
void setNextNode(T &&nodeValue) {
        nextNode = std::make_unique<Node<T>>(nodeValue);
}
```

And add like this:

```
root->setNextNode(88);
```

Also make_unique is part of c++14, if you are working with c++11 use reset:

```
nextNode.reset(new Node<T>(nodeValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the reccomended way of using `unique_ptr`s: instead of creating your objects with `new`, you can use `std::make_unique`, which automatically wraps the object inside a unique pointer.

You are also mixing raw and unique pointers, which is bad because it can lead to confusion about who's the owner of the passed objects. Below is an example of better list:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> nextNode = nullptr;

    Node(T dataIn) : data(dataIn) {

    }

    void setNextNode(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& nodeIn) {
      std::swap(nextNode, nodeIn);
    }

    void printData() {
      std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};




int main() {
  auto root = std::make_unique<Node<int>>(26);
  auto nodeTwo = std::make_unique<Node<int>>(88);
  root->setNextNode(std::move(nodeTwo));

}
```

Note the use of `std::move` and `std::swap` to properly transfer ownership.